# SharpRepository .NET Core no implementation for asynchronous operations

Tags: .net-core, sharp-repository

I have just started using SharpRepository to replace our current GenericRepository in my .NET Core project. It's an API project which need to handle large amount of concurrent requests. However, I could not find any implementation for asynchronous operations. Is there any specific reason for that? Should I just wrap synchronous SharpRepository operations in a Task run if I want to go asynchronous all the way?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is this here: https://github.com/SharpRepository/SharpRepository/issues/53#issuecomment-18109624

To make a good work we need to develop async methods for all implementations (EF, Mongo ...). Not easy. If you can help make a PR!